# protect first row against deletion

Tags: excel, vba

I have an protected excel sheet with command button to delete rows.
Users can highlight and select multiple rows and delete them by clicking on command button. But I do not want the first row (row no.11) to be deleted because it contains formulas and formatting. I have below code in command button to delete. It works fine and protects row no.11 when the user highlights and selects row from row no.11 to 40 (because here the active row is 11). But the problem is when user highlights the rows from button of sheet and clicks on command button, then it EVEN deletes row no.11 because the active row here is more than 11 (example active row=40). Please expalin how I can protect the row no.11 against deletion by user even when they select it for deletion.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
If ActiveCell.Row > 11 Then
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxx"
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Protect "xxx", True, True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: after deleting rows you can write again these formulas using `.Range("A1").Formula ` method. just hard-code the formulas before `end sub` in above code

Comment: @Maddy Nikam - I used the below syntax. I did not fully understand your syntax. Can you please explain a bit or an example would be great... thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Check if the user has selected Row 11 or not

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Variant

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Selection

    '~~> Check if the user has selected Row 11
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If rw.Row = 11 Then
            MsgBox "Please do not select Row 11"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rw

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "xxx"
    rng.Rows.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Protect "xxx", True, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great ! your syntax works superb ! thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)